# When does docker-compose build a local image and when does it pull from docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

Following the tutorial of docker compose. Let's say you have a Dockerfile for your app and docker-compose.yml for its services.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
...
COPY . /myapp
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    image: dre-hh/myapp
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp

    depends_on:
      - db
```

While developing you would like to build the app from the local filesystem with docker-compose. Then later you could upload the app docker image to docker hub.

Do you need separted overridable configurations if you want to choose between building from local system or from docker hub? Or is it possible 
somehow else as one can specify both build and image options on the yaml file?

Comment: I would say yes. You need more configs. OR just one docker compose to run the composed configuration and a separate step to build the container with docker itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using **build:** with **image:**, the image name is simply to let you choose which name that docker-compose will tag the image as.
To push images, you should use a different config / build workflow, as lvonet mentioned